# How to add value of checked checkbox to textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, text

How can I use jQuery to delete the text in the `textarea` that gets from the `input_one` when it not checked (`one_1 one_3 one_4`) ,and when it checked add it into `textarea` again?

The code is below:

```
<div id="input_one">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one_1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one_2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one_3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one_4">
</div>
<div id="input_two">
  <input type="checkbox" value="two_1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="two_2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="two_3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="two_4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="two_5">
</div>    
<textarea id="get_checked"></textarea>
```

For example textarea value should be `one one_3 two_4`

Comment: Umn, this is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Comment: We meet again Mr. altCognito. I was going to link him to the same page that we both just answered earlier today, haha. We have no lives...

Comment: So true, so true, our schedules must match or something. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
function updateTextArea() {
    var allVals = [];
    $('#input_one :checked,#input_two :checked').each(function () {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#get_checked').val(allVals);
}
$(function () {
    $('#input_one input,#input_two input').click(updateTextArea);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCFkQ/)

Comment: This  worked for me as expected. Simple easy to read code. Thx Pundit.

Answer (score 1):

You can select `checked` checkbox using [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to replace item of checkboxs array with value of it.

```
$("#input_one :checkbox, #input_two :checkbox").change(function() {   
    var text = $("#input_one :checked, #input_two :checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(" ");
    $("#get_checked").val(text);
});
```

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {   
    var text = $(":checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(" ");
    $("#get_checked").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input_one">
    <input type="checkbox" value="one" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="one_1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="one_2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="one_3" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="one_4" />
</div>
<div id="input_two">
    <input type="checkbox" value="two_1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="two_2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="two_3" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="two_4" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="two_5" />
</div>
<textarea id="get_checked"></textarea>
```

As you said in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/788100/5104748), the resutl text splited by space.