# Find checkbox values from Dynamically generated Divs in php using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How to find checkbox values from Dynamically generated Divs in php using javascript?

Here is my code,

```
echo "<input type='text' name='chkID' id='chkID'>
   <div id='mainDiv'>";

 while($rowset = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<div style='float:left; width=10px; border:solid 1px;'>
    <input type='checkbox' value =".$rowset[0].">".$rowset[0]."</div>
   <div style='float:left; width=200px; border:solid 1px;'>".$rowset[1].''.$rowset[2]."
   </div></br></br>";
  }

 echo '</div>';
```

I want to display the values of checkboxes selected which would be like (1,2,3) in the `chkID` textbox... I want it to be done using javascript...

Comment: u can use jquery like :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Comment: @haim he was asking for javascript i think so..

Comment: @Felix i agree with u... If he wanted it to be done in jquery he would have tagged jquery for the above question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this might be what you're looking for.

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
var inputs = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        values.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add an unique name `name` and `id` to the input tags:

```
echo "...
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox".$num."' id='checkbox".$num."' value ='".$rowset[0]."' />
...";
$num++;
```

(Also you need too look at your syntax: missing quotes (') and at the end of the tag a slash (/))

Then you can find the checkboxes with this simple JavaScript:

```
alert(document.findElementById("checkbox1").value);
```

Change the number to find the other checkboxes. Use a loop or something if you want to find all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the work:

`var div= document.getElementById('mainDiv');

var txt=document.getElementById('chkID');

var children=div.children;

for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++)

{

    if(children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase()=='div')

 {

    if(children[i].children !=null && children[i].children.length>0 && children[i].children[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()=='input' )

  {

    txt.value=txt.value + ' ' + children[i].children[0].value;

  }

 }

}`