# JQuery to determine if all checkboxlists (in div) have been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkboxlist

I am trying to use jQuery to do some validation on a form; I need a method where I can validate if all controls in a  have been filled out \ selected. The CheckBoxLists my application supports are giving me a hard time as it seems like jQuery likes to address each checkboxes individually, but what I really need to do is evaluate all CBLs in a div and know if each has had at least one individual box checked.

I can name the DIV and the individual CBL's IDs as I see fit (so can do CBL1, CBL2, etc.). I really need a way to parse everything in a

Comment: Could you give us some rendered HTML? CheckBoxLists are not an HTML concept, but a Microsoft one that gets translated to HTML.

Comment: even this answer might be useful to see how to traverse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that ASP parses your CBL as such:

```
<h2>Interests</h2>
<ul id='CBL1' class='checkboxlist'>
    <li><input type='checkbox' name='interest' value='javascript'> JavaScript</li>
    <li><input type='checkbox' name='interest' value='jquery'> jQuery</li>
</ul>
<h2>Hobbies</h2>
<ul id='CBL2' class='checkboxlist'>
    <!-- subsequent data -->
```

You could check this doing something like:

```
function validateCBLs() {
    var $lists = $('ul.checkboxlist');
    $lists.each(function(i, item) {
        if ($(item).find(':checked').length < 1) {
            //Show user an error, etc
            alert('Please, check at least one item from ' + $(item).attr('id'));
        }
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/clarkf/sapEU/)

Comment: +1 but... Why the $ signs in front of the variable name? Oh, and you need a var statement in there.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, some people prefix jQuery selector variables with `$` to identify it as a jQuery selector. I don't always, and I couldn't tell you why I did it here... Fixed the var statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 1 checkbox in each list selected.  Wonder if this would work (make all the CBL's have an ID that starts with 'CBL' (eg. CBL1, CBL2,...)):

```
var valid = true;
$('[id^="CBL"]').each(function(i,v){
    valid = valid && ($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').size() >= 1);
});
alert(valid);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDssg/)

Comment: This checks if all checkboxes have been checked, not all checkbox *lists*.

Comment: @Rocket - It's a control in ASP.Net, rendered as a table or flow layout of checkboxes

Comment: A checkbox list contains checkboxes, right?  So, why wouldn't this work?

Comment: @Rocket - You're requiring *every* checkbox in *every* list to be checked, not at least one in each.

Comment: @Nick- Oh.  Thanks.  Ignore this answer then.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasBoxesChecked(id) {
  return $(":checkbox:checked", document.getElementById(id)).length > 0;
}
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/Vewmg/)

Comment: Note: demo uses actual output from two ASP.NET CheckBoxList controls

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.checkboxlist').filter(function(){
            return $(this).find(':checked').size()>0;
        }).size()
```

This will give you the number of CBLs that has at least one checkbox selected.