# I already have 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox in asp.net webform when i check 1and 2 checkbox then result in textbox will be 1,2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I already have 3 checkboxes and 1 textbox in asp.net webform when i check 1and 2 checkbox then result in textbox will be 1,2

I have the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test(control, value) {
        var str = '';
        if (control.checked) {
          str = value + '\n' + $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>').val();
        }
        else {
            str = $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>').val().replace(value + '\n', '');  
        }
        $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>').val(str);
    }
</script>
```

to do this......

But the problem in this code ...was when i check 3 and 2 checkbox then result in the textbox is 3,2,

But i want it appear as 2,3 only ...

Can anybody reedit this code ....... ??????

I would be thank ful to u ..............

Comment: what does the markup look like that calls this?

Answer (score 1):

What if you just reverse the output?

`$('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>').val().split(",").reverse().join(",");`

Comment: It just reveses the values of your checkboxes. So "3,2" becomes "2,3". You probably want to use it right before you submit the form.

Comment: But if the user checks 2,3, user still wants 2,3 to display correct?

Comment: Good call. I was trying to keep their original code usable. That said it doesn't appear  the OP wants to put any effort into figuring this out so I'm not going to put any more effort in my answer :P

Answer (score 1):

This function is triggered when user clicks check box. So if you click 2 & 3 by this order, them there is everything right?

So user "each" sentence:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test(control, value) {
     var str = '';
     $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %> :checked').each(function() {
       str = str + ', ' $(this).val();
     });
     $('#<%=txtTest.ClientID %>').val(str);

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you try and figure it out?

Comment: I m confused how to do that ..... i have discovered the top most code mentioned above....

all the problems m facing is memtioned above can anybody in this earth solve my problem ?

Comment: How to call this function on checkbox check event ?

Comment: I have call this as :

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chktest1" value="one" onclick="Test(this,this.value)" />one</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chktest2" value="two" onclick="Test(this,this.value)" />two</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chktest3" value="three" onclick="Test(this,this.value)" />three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        
Object Expected Error when i check chckbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Comment: I wanna use Asp.net Standard control to do this !!