# Comma separated list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, serialization, checkbox

I'm trying to create a comma separated list from what is checked on the form.

```
var $StateIDs = $(':checked');
var StateIDs = '';
for (i=0, j = $StateIDs.length; i < j; i++) {
    StateIDs += $StateIDs[i].val();
    if (i == j) break;
    StateIDs += ',';
}
```

There's probably a 1-liner that can do this, or a single function.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is going to be your friend here.

```
var StateIDs = $(':checked').map(function() { 
    return this.value; 
}).get().join(',');
```

StateIDs will be a comma-separated string.

---

**Step-by-step - What is going on?**

```
$(':checked')
// Returns jQuery array-like object of all checked inputs in the document
// Output: [DOMElement, DOMElement]

$(':checked').map(fn);
// Transforms each DOMElement based on the mapping function provided above
// Output: ["CA", "VA"]  (still a jQuery array-like object)

$(':checked').map(fn).get();
// Retrieve the native Array object from within the jQuery object
// Output: ["CA", "VA"]

$(':checked').map(fn).get().join(',');
// .join() will concactenate each string in the array using ','
// Output: "CA,VA"
```

Comment: John, I've got one more question: Who is the man?  A: You are!

Comment: You are too kind sir, enjoy the rest of your Tuesday!

Comment: This answer should be the model for which all SO questions are answered. Thanks for the effort, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
var ids = '';
$(':checked').each(function(){
    ids += $(this).val() + ',';
});
```

Writing blind, so I have not tested.

Comment: Tim, when I can snatch the pebbles from your hand, it will be time for me to leave.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery). It gives you nicely simplified code for exactly what you're doing.