# how to get the checked box input value by jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the input check box  code:

```
<li class="odd"><input type="checkbox"  class="forminput" name="VD10" checked="checked" value="http://test1.com">
<a href="#">example 1</a></li>

<li class="even><input type="checkbox"  class="forminput" name="VD11" checked="checked" value="http://test2.com">
<a href="#">example 1</a></li>

<li class="odd"><input type="checkbox"  class="forminput" name="VD12" checked="checked" value="http://test3.com">
<a href="#">example 1</a></li>........
```

the button code:

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" name="checkall" checked="checked"> 
<label for="checkall">check all</label>
<input type="button" value="copy the checked link" class="button">
</li>
```

now, i want to do when click the `copy the checked link` button. it will copy the checked input value to the clipboard? how do i do?

Comment: If only one link should be checked, you should be using radio buttons, not check boxes. If more than one can be checked, which one do you want copied?

Comment: the number of links will be copied which are optionally.as there may be one or more check boxes be checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".button").click( function () {
           var selectedCheckboxValue = "";
          $('input.forminput:checked').each(function() {

                  selectedCheckboxValue += $(this).val() + ", ";

          });
          alert(selectedCheckboxValue);
   });
```

click here see the working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/t5TKm/

Comment: i want to output the result one by one. namely. the value shows as line by line. and no sign , after it? how do i do?

Comment: if i delete the ","  comma, when i checked two box. the output only have one result. not two results. why?

Comment: Just use `selectedCheckboxValue += $(this).val() + "\n";` instead of `selectedCheckboxValue += $(this).val() + ", ";` - That will give you the output line by line

Comment: Use [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) this to capture the output in the clipboard works on all platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy to the clipboard without flash, silverlight, or some other rich-client plugin.

But, here is the answer to that question: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

And: [How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)

Comment: The two links in my answer address that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.getElementByTag('VD10').checked` to check if the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: Only IE provides functionality to Copy to clipboard in windows, for rest you need flash