# checked checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating the checkboxes and corresponding ids for them dynamically as shown, according to the values in which I'm getting from back end.
Once it has been created, how could I retrieve the values of this checked checkboxes?

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
   <td class="valueleft">All</td>
   <td class="valueleft"><input type='checkbox' id="cb1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="valueleft">--------</td>
   <td class="valueleft">----checkbox-------</td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#myTable").last().append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td><input type='checkbox'id="+id+"/></td></tr>");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the values of the checked checkobxes you could do something like:

```
var checkedValues = [];

$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
       //here this refers to the checkbox you are iterating on
       checkedValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

or if you want name/values pair you could do:

```
var checkedValues = {};

$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
       //here this refers to the checkbox you are iterating on
       checkedValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});

//you end up with an object with the id's as properties and the relative values as values
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it didn't work"!What do you need to do exactl?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use .map:

```
var checkedVals = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```