# send the items in the email if the check box is checked

Tags: jquery, forms

i am building an estimates form and I need to send by email only the div's with checked box. how to script it with jquery? I guess I must first get all the checked boxes and unchecked ones and eliminate from the form the correspondent div of the unchecked box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` pseudoselector to select checkboxes that are checked:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

Or to get checkboxes that are *not* checked:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)");
```

Or to get checked checkboxes inside of your correspondent div:

```
$("#correspondent input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

**EDIT**

So you want divs that have checkboxes, none of which are checked?  This will do that

```
var divsWithoutChecked = 
    $("div:has(input[type='checkbox'])")
       .filter(function () { 
          return $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length === 0 
     });
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but actually I need to select the div with no checked boxes and delete them from the form in order to send by email only the selected items

Comment: @EmilioYero - Also, I don't think you need to delete unchecked checkboxes from the form -- I'm pretty sure only checked checkboxes' values will post when you submit

Answer (score 0):

to send the email , you need to have a server side page (ASP.NET/ PHP / ASP etc..).. You may check whether the checkbox is checked then make a jQuery ajax call to the server page where you execute the code to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

See here to get the value of a checkbox: [How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)

Now, you'll want to do a `$.each` on the divs in question, and then make an array out of the ones that you want to send, and then process that array.