# How to get the values of multiple checkboxes with the same class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the values of all checkboxes that are currently checked using jquery, I suppose I would put it all in an array, but I am having trouble doing that. Would anyone be able to point me in the write direction.

This is what I am using so far. I am trying to send all of the values that are currently checked to a div I have.

```
function cityPopulate() {


        var arr44 = new Array();   
        var cityNames22 = $("input[name=city_select[]]:checked").each(function(){arr44.push(this.value);});



        $("#city_pop").append(cityNames22.val());
    }

        When I try the code above, it just gives me the value of the first checkbox I check only. Not all of the rest.
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far.

Comment: Possible duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the code you have I'm guessing at your exact schema, but using `map()` on your checkboxes with the class you specify to create an array should work, try this:

```
var checkboxValues = $('.myCheckbox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

`checkboxValues` would then contain an array with all the values of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: This actually working cause I see in the javascript error it giving me all of the values now, but how would I display this array. Now it just won't display, it give me the error "object has no method val"

Comment: To display an array as a string you need to `join()` it - `$("#city_pop").append(checkboxValues.join(','));`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the class you have assigned to your checkboxes, it will look something like this:

```
var values = [];

$('.checkboxclass').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(':checked')) {
    values.push($this.val());
  }
});
```