# dropdown list based on checkbox

Tags: php, html

i have few checkboxes named as HR,visitor,gaurd now i want to get which ever chckbox is selected  according to it names of the employee belonging to that team whether HR or Guard or visitor to be shown in dropdown list

```
<select name=cmbname id="cmbname" width='50%'>
```

ALL

`

```
    $objDB->SetQuery($sql);

    $res = $objDB->GetQueryReference();

    if(!$res)
        exit("Error in SQL : $sql");

    if($objDB->GetNumRows($res) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
        {

                print("
            <option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</option>");

        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($res);
```

?>'

Comment: show the appropriate code please.

Comment: what you are tried?? please show it

Comment: lol, first answer always seems to be jQuery related

Comment: paste some code which you tried....

Comment: @JonTaylor because this solution is best accomplished with jQuery.

Comment: @DainisAbols no, it may be simpler, it is not necesserily best accomplished with it.  It is a trivial task in standard javascript without the use of jQuery.  Using jQuery libraries unfortunately seems to be the first answer to every javascript question on SO, people are starting to forget how to actually use standard javascript which means when jQuery can't solve their problem they sit there thinking the world has coem to an end. (Something I see quite often unfortunately).

Comment: new to php n javascript so want  to know the code to strat with

Comment: i have desinged the HTML page now just want to know how to get values in the option  tag

Answer (score 0):

Himani ,

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery/786215#786215). Hope it will be useful to you. Instead of text-area you can use drop-down.

Comment: thanx but i have used drop down want to fill option tag based on checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this way gives you solution

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //javascript 
 function clicked_checkbox()
 {  
   document.form.submit();  
 }
 </script>
 <?php
 $hr = isset($_REQUEST['HR'])?$_REQUEST['HR']:false;
 $guest = isset($_REQUEST['guest'])?$_REQUEST['guest']:false;
 $visiter = isset($_REQUEST['visiter'])?$_REQUEST['visiter']:false;

//Prepare query with retrieved value and put value in Dropdown
$sql = 'select * from table ';
if($hr)      { $sql .= "where user = '$hr'" };
if($guest)   { $sql .= "where user = '$guest'" };
if($visiter) { $sql .= "where user = '$hr'" };

$objDB->SetQuery($sql);
$res = $objDB->GetQueryReference();

if(!$res)
    exit("Error in SQL : $sql");

if($objDB->GetNumRows($res) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        print("<option value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</option>");
    }
}
mysql_free_result($res);
?>

//on change of checkbox we'll call above function and set data to dropdown
<form name='form' method='get' action='#'>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_HR" name="HR" value="true" <?php if($hr) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onchange="return clicked_checkbox();">
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_guest" name="guest" value="true" <?php if($guest) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onchange="return clicked_checkbox();">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_user" name="visiter" value="true" <?php  if($visiter) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> onchange="return clicked_checkbox();">
 </form>
```

like this you can achieve :)

Comment: tried using this but it is showing me entire list i.e dropdown is not dependnt on checkbox

Comment: this works for me !! you have to check your query that might have problem or show me your query