# How do I get a checkbox value

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this has been asked many times before but I'm not sure what will work for me. I'm pretty JQ illiterate but working on it.

I need to get the checkbox values so that I can process them on the server. Currently, I get a POST value for checked but nothing for unchecked. Can someone please show me how to get the unchecked value?

```
$(this).next()[0].checked = !$(this).next()[0].checked;
var vals = $(this).next().serializeArray();
```

Comment: This should answer it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Comment: Thank you for the link, bukfixart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var val = $(this).is(':checked');
```

Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/Ut69Q/) proving it works

Comment: despite the downvote, this is how you get the value of a checkbox. see fiddle

Comment: Why were you downvoted? Granted, I know diddly about JQuery but this doesn't look like a bad answer to me.

Comment: Well, I just upvoted you and I'm selecting this as the right answer. Thank you for your help!