# Using jQuery how can I get the value of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)

I have the following form:

```
<form action="index.php">
    <div class="answer"><input type="radio" name="vote_answers" value="3615736&1047558" class="vote_answers"> 1</div>

    <div class="answer"><input type="radio" name="vote_answers" value="3615736&1121626" class="vote_answers"> 2</div>

    <div class="answer"><input type="radio" name="vote_answers" value="3615736&9910782" class="vote_answers"> 3</div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button_submit_vote" value="submit">
</form>
```

When i click on **submit** I need to get the value of checked checkboxes

This is my code:

```
$('#button_submit_vote').on('click',function() {
    if($('.vote_answers').is(':checked')){var id=$(this).val();}
    alert(id);
});
```

Instead of the checkbox value I get value "submit".

Comment: this should in this case point to button for form submit, or to be precise this = $('#button_submit_vote'). $('.vote_answers').val() perhaps is what you are looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `this` refers to `button_submit_vote` element, you can `:checked` selector:

```
var id = $('.vote_answers:checked').val();
```

Comment: @LeoLex if this answered your question please use the checkmark to the left to mark it as such.

Comment: sure) i cannt becose was need time for this. thank you)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been that far:
`$('.vote_answers:checked').val()`