# getting the values from checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the checkboxes and its values are populated from the database. I can select and deselect all the checkbox but I am not able to get the values of individual checked checkbox. This is what I have done so far, 
 for the checkbox populating from database:

```
<form>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="All"> <b>Select/DeSelect All</b><br>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT Subject_Category from {extdb_subjects} where level=1 ';
$res = db_query($sql);

foreach ($res as $row)
{
 echo "<input type='checkbox' id='sub_names' name='{$row->Subject_Category}'
    value='{$row->Subject_Category}'";

  echo ">{$row->Subject_Category}";
  echo "<br>";
}
?>

</form>
```

JQuery script for selecting de selecting all the check box and individual display of the checked checkbox:

```
jQuery(function(){

 jQuery('#All').change(function() {


    var checkboxes = jQuery(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');

    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');


    } else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');

    }


    });

  jQuery('#sub_names').change(function() { //This is not able to get the values

    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert(jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked").val());


    } 


    });

});
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery

Comment: Your problem is you have many element with same ID (I think) so only the first one will have your onChange handler.

Comment: @RC yes, because of that only first element value show up when clicking the checkbox and for the rest it has no effect.

Comment: Use a class and not an ID

Comment: Yes, use classes not ids. But you still have a problem in that `.val()` will return only the value of the first selected element. If you want to alert the values of all selected elements then you will need to build a string by looping through the jQuery selection.

Comment: The examples in jQuery's documentation for [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) detail a potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems odd to me. You check to see if *this* is checked, then you try to grab some arbitrary checked box value. Try this.

```
jQuery('#sub_names').change(function() { //This is not able to get the values
  if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert(jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked").val());
  } 
}
```

try:

```
   jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
         console.log( $(this).val() )
       }
   })
```