# How to check checkbox for only checked item on jquery success function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

As I need to check only the items which has value true from controller on jQuery success function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#Pid").change(function () 
         {
            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getcheckedchannel","Channels")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { pid: $(this).val() },
            success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                    {
                       //if (data[i].IsChecked == "1") {
                       var status = data[i].IsChecked ? true : false;
                       $(".IsCheck").attr("checked", status);
                      //}
                     }
            }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: share your html also and the contents of data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].IsChecked) {
        // Your logic goes here
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can just write this

```
data[i].IsChecked ? $(".IsCheck").prop("checked", true) : '';
```

Also consider using .**prop** instead of .**attr** to set the checked property