# Jquery get one or more checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

Hello i have html table where i list database result. All database items have self checkbox with value item id:

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" id="row" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->id);?>"> </td>
```

Now i want to take one or more checked item and that value to put in my url like last param.

```
<a onclick="return Form.deleteItem(this);" href="<?php echo $this->url('phonebook', array('action'=>'edit', 'id' => '1'));?>">
    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml('Edit');?>
</a>
```

I want that add value to in url like this.

http://www.example.com/edit/1

So if user check one item and click on edit how to put that value in url like last param

I try this  but dont work:

```
deleteItem: function(obj) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#row").is(':checked')) {
            //read line
            var queryString = $("#row").val();
            // Loop 
            var s = $("#row").siblings();
            $.each(s, function() {
                // see if checked
                if ($("#row").is(":checked")) {
                    queryString += 'OR' + $("#row").val();
                }
            });

            console.log(queryString);

            // Append to url 
        }
    });

},
```

Comment: All ids among one HTML page must be unique. So if you have multiple rows using `id="row"` your HTML isn't valid. In this case use a class or a data-attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right. Here's an example on how to achieve this. This code will append all selected values comma separated to either the `edit` or `delete` routes.

**HTML**

```
<label><input class="row" type="checkbox" value="1"> 1</label>
<label><input class="row" type="checkbox" value="2"> 2</label>
<label><input class="row" type="checkbox" value="3"> 3</label>
<label><input class="row" type="checkbox" value="4"> 4</label>

<a class="action" href="http://www.example.com/edit/">Edit</a> 
<a class="action" href="http://www.example.com/delete/">Delete</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('a.action').click(function() {
    var v = $('input.row:checked').map(function () { return this.value; }).get().join(',');

    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + v);
});
```

The code to map and join the values is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116631/1456376).

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/SBEy5/)

Answer (score 0):

insertusernamehere is absolutely correct. Your HTML is invalid, and the jQuery function only returns the first checkbox with the id of "row". Here's an example:

HTML:

```
Row Checkboxes: <br />
<input id="row" type="checkbox" name="checkboxOne" value="yes" />
<input id="row" type="checkbox" name="checkboxTwo" checked="checked" value="yes" />
<br />
Test checkboxes:<br />
<input id="test" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="checkboxThree" value="yes" />
<input id="test" type="checkbox" name="checkboxFour" value="yes" />
```

JS:

```
//returns false, because it gets the value of only the first #row checkbox
console.log($('#row').is(':checked'));

//returns true, because it only gets the checked attribute of the first #test checkbox
console.log($('#test').is(':checked'));

//only returns the first #row box
console.log(document.getElementById('row'))
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Br85c/1/