# Get the values from multiple checkboxes and calculate them

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes with different id's:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="3.99" id="one" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="5.99" id="two">
<input type="checkbox" value="7.99" id="three">
```

And also a field with total value of checked boxes:

```
<div id="total">3.99</div>
```

I need simplest jquery solution to calculate values on the go. For example if I check id's "one" and "two" the div "total" should look like this:

```
<div id="total">9.98</div>
```

Comment: I tried different solutions but the code was redundunt. To many if's.

Comment: Where would you use this, I mean this is sheer hardcoding and I dont recommend this...

Comment: According to me, you are going to be voted down so badly...

Comment: @DanglingPointer he may be getting those values dynamically..

Comment: Ok fine, but there are too many questions asked already that how to bind an event and how you can get the value of a check box.

Comment: There are atleast 3-4 answers already... Вячеслав Неговский Please mark as correct...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786142/how-to-retrieve-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

you can write something in this way:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {

 if(this.checked)
    $('#total').text(parseFloat($('#total').text()) + parseFloat($(this).val()))

}).trigger("change")
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zch11bjo/)

### REVISED:

This one is more perfect and effective.

### HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3.99" id="one" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="5.99" id="two">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="7.99" id="three">
<div id="total">0</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    var sum = 0;


    $('.check').each(function () {

        if (this.checked) sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());

    });

    $('#total').text(sum)

}).trigger("change")
```

[**REVISED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zch11bjo/1/)

Comment: There's overflow if check/uncheck few times :(

Comment: what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var $cbs = $(':checkbox');
$cbs.change(function(){
var total = 0; //$("#more").val();
$cbs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
alert(total);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdp2uw0q/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#total").html(total);
}
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/vnwL92b4/

try it